# Question on Java methods

Tags: java

I got a question. I am given a linked-list Node with the parameter of A val and Node next. I also given a function call join which will join the end of list x to to y.

> *5 |-> 6 |-> 7 |-> null*

```
Node x = new Node(5, new Node(6, new Node(7, null))); 
this.join(x, x) 

    public void join(Node x, Node y){
   if(x.next==null){
      x.next = y;
   }else{
     join(x.next, y);
   }
}
```

and when I get the length is only 3. Can I how come is not a stack overflow instead?

Comment: Can we see the length() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how come is not a stack overflow
>   instead?

Because the list still has an end before the call to `join()` terminates. If you call it *again*, however...

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I check again and it turn out to be overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The join function looks good, but **if you invoke it with `this.join(x,x)` you build some kind of circle**!

So if you do something recursive with `x` after `this.join(x,x)`, you will possible get some kind of stack overflow because of an endless recusrion.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your reply and it indeed turn into an overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is only one instance of node x, and you build up circle in your list. You will never reach x.next==null. You should probably check for some equality.

Comment: Hi thanks.You are right! it was my code that was the problem.